# ckeditor assets are precompilling at each capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, capistrano

I have used `Rails 4.1`, `capistrano "2.15"`, `ckeditor` gems .

While deploying each time the ckeditor files are being precompiled .

I have set

```
Ckeditor.setup do |config|
  config.assets_languages = ['en', 'fr']
  config.assets_plugins = ['image', 'smiley']
end
```

Is there anything need to set ?

Thanks in advance

```
cp -p public/assets/ckeditor/filebrowser/images/gal_more-54fcc8b86e58e7c1c1cc043f32c5fbe7.gif public/assets/ckeditor/filebrowser/images/gal_more.gif
 cp -p public/assets/ckeditor/filebrowser/images/thumbs/ckfnothumb-7e8c7fcbddcd0db1923649991a3234ac.gif public/assets/ckeditor/filebrowser/images/thumbs/ckfnothumb.gif
 cp -p public/assets/ckeditor/filebrowser/images/thumbs/xlsx-c28d62bddfa353a5b2fa3642938cdd16.gif public/assets/ckeditor/filebrowser/images/thumbs/xlsx.gif
 cp -p public/assets/ckeditor/filebrowser/images/thumbs/mpg-6d0b2d9ff3f72d2b7dc3cc3c75b08839.gif public/assets/ckeditor/filebrowser/images/thumbs/mpg.gif
 cp -p public/assets/ckeditor/filebrowser/images/thumbs/gz-89f8f9b7bbe463dee3eeb45d067d0419.gif public/assets/ckeditor/filebrowser/images/thumbs/gz.gif
 cp -p public/assets/ckeditor/filebrowser/images/thumbs/txt-06fcaae88a48515d65ab0b00f6cb7ca4.gif public/assets/ckeditor/filebrowser/images/thumbs/txt.gif
 cp -p public/assets/ckeditor/filebrowser/images/thumbs/pdf-86514f2251b84ab7c3eaafab821f9799.gif public/assets/ckeditor/filebrowser/images/thumbs/pdf.gif
```